# URL changes but component doesn't render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I have a below react component with following render function, which displays list of employees.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.props.list.response.map(list => (
              <tr key={list._id}>
                <td>
                  <Link to={`/admin/profiles/employee/${list._id}`}>{list.name}</Link>
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

this component works fine and it displays the names as I want them to be. Now when I click on the name I want to render a profile component. So when above url/route matches then render profile component. I do that in App.js container which is below:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/' exact={true} component={LoginPage} />
          <Route path='/login' component={LoginPage} />
      <PrivateRoute path='/admin' component={Header} />
          <PrivateRoute path='/admin/profiles/employee/:id' component={Profiles} /> // --> here it is
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The problem is that the url changes but the component is not rendering. Below is my very basic profile component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Profiles extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>Profiles</div>
    );
  }
}

export default Profiles;
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I render this profile component?

**UPDATE**

When I moved the order of routes in App.js then it does work but then I loose Header component in profiles component. How can I retain Header component there?

```
      <PrivateRoute path='/admin/profiles/employee/:id' component={Profiles} /> // --> here it is
      <PrivateRoute path='/admin' component={Header} />
```

Above solves one issue but creates another as explained above.

Comment: Where is the first code snippet located in your app? All `Link` components need to have the `BrowserRouter` component as ancestor.

Comment: What do you mean by BrowserRouter as ancestor?

Comment: `Link` components need to have `BrowserRouter` above it in the tree or clicking on one of them will not have any effect on the `Route` components.

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: Here `Link` has `BrowserRouter` as ancestor:`<BrowserRouter><div><Link> ... </Link></div></BrowserRouter>`. Here it does not: `<BrowserRouter> ... </BrowserRouter><Link> ... </Link>`

Comment: Here is what I did `<BrowserRouter>
                  <td>
                    <Link to={`/admin/profiles/employee/${list._id}`}>{list.name}</Link>
                  </td>
                </BrowserRouter>` now it still does not render the profiles.

Comment: It has to be the same `BrowserRouter` you use for the `Route` components. Just one `BrowserRouter` at the top of your app.

Comment: You mean I should add it in App.js file not in a component that has render mentioned above?

Comment: I'm not sure what more to say. Please look at the examples in the documentation. Try `<BrowserRouter><div><Link to="/admin/profiles/employee/foo"> Foo </Link><Switch><PrivateRoute path='/admin/profiles/employee/:id' component={Profiles} /></Switch></div></BrowserRouter>`

Comment: Can you please post an answer in detail if possible?

Comment: Try keeping routes in the original order and adding `exact={true}` to the `Header` component route.